# WiX - How to define only Feature tree UI

Tags: wix

I've used the WixUI_FeatureTree dialog set but what I really need is a UI with the feature selection dialog, nothing else. WixUI dialog library contains the CustomizeDlg dialog which I understand to be the feature selection. I can't find any docs on using a single library dialog. Tried copying WixUI_FeatureTree.wxs fragment to my WXS and modifying it but I'm missing declaration or references (`The Windows Installer XML variable !(wix.WixUICostingPopupOptOut) is unknown.`). I'm using WiX v3.7 over VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the line

```
<UIRef Id="WixUI_Common" />
```

to the product element (best after </UI> ). this shold solve the ... variable ... is unknown error. then try to follow the "Changing the UI sequence of a built-in dialog set" example of this page: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/WixUI_customizations.htm